# How do I remove duplicates from tree set with Custom Objects

Tags: java, duplicates, treeset

I have an ArrayList (cntct) of ParseMessage's. ParseMessage has the

```
private long dateSent;
private String contact;
private String body;
```

with the getters and setters generated by eclipse. 
I am trying to get the most recent message from each contact.
So I decided to do it as such

```
SortedSet<ParseMessage> cntctList = new TreeSet<ParseMessage>(new Comparator<ParseMessage>() {
@Override
public int compare(ParseMessage o1, ParseMessage o2)
{   
    if(o1 == null || o2 == null)
        return 0;
    if(o1.getContact().equals(o2.getContact()))
        return 0;
    if(o1.getDateSent() <= o2.getDateSent())
        return 1;
    return -1;
}           
});
cntctList.addAll(cntct);
```

I seemed to have missed something in this though, as I am still getting a limited number of duplicates. I am using maybe 100 messages with 5 contacts and the set ends up with a size of 7

EDIT:

ParseMessage does override .equals and .hasCode As such

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return getContact().hashCode();
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object e) {
    if(!(e instanceof ParseMessage))
    {
        return false;
    }

    return ((ParseMessage) e).getContact().equals(getContact());
}
```

END:

Also this is for a web based call. If anyone see's a way to make this faster then I would love to hear ideas.

Comment: have you implemented `hashCode` and `equals` for class `ParseMessage`. Duplicate in `Set` has nothing to do with `comparator` but `hashCode` and `equals`.

Comment: Yes I have. Edit Above Shows what they are

Comment: You can't use `TreeSet` and `Comparator` for that, because your `Comparator` is violating the rules of [compare()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-), e.g. it is not *transitive*.

Comment: @ShubhenduPramanik You do *not* have to implement `hashCode` and `equals` when using a `TreeSet`, only when using a `HashSet`. A `TreeSet` never calls those methods, and equality (aka "duplicate") is entirely defined by the given `Comparator` returning `0`.

Comment: .equals for ParseMessage should be something like (o1.getContact().equals(o2.getContact()) && o1.getDateSent().equals(o2.getDateSent()) thereby comparing both at the same time.  (probably should throw body in there as well)

Comment: @BrentR `equals` has no meaning when using `TreeSet`

Comment: @Andreas so what would be my fastes way of achieving this

Comment: @BrentR my equals is specifically targeted for parts of my app and cant compare time and body. technically you are right but I am using it differently

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the problem causing your issue here, but I did notice _a_ problem with your code: You are returning 0 immediately if the contacts match, regardless of what the date is. What I would do instead is keep the null check, and replace the rest of the checks with a simple `return o2.getDateSent() - o1.getDateSent()`

Comment: @Andreas if `hashCode` and `equals` is not required then how does `TreeSet` compare two elements while adding? Do you mean for above code only it's not required? Any link to source code for what you are saying would be helpful. Thanks...

Comment: I stand by my comment based on the definition of a Set.  No duplicates.

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat I return 0 immediately to let the tree set know that these two are equal and that one of them should be removed from the tree.

Comment: @ShubhenduPramanik A `TreeSet` sorts values according to the `compare` / `compareTo` method. A return value of `0` means that the objects are equal. It in the definition of the methods.

Comment: @Andreas Yes I agree with this... but what about uniqueness of `Set`/ `TreeSet`?

Comment: @ShubhenduPramanik Not sure I understand your comment. Uniqueness is defined by equality, and a `TreeSet` defines equality as a `compare` return value of `0`, so if `compare` returns `0`, one of the objects will not be added to the set.

Comment: @ShubhenduPramanik it gets the uniqueness by the 0 return value. so if it compares the first and second value and gets a return of 0. then it throws out the second value.

Comment: @Andreas this makes sense... I thought this comparison is only for sorting the elements. Thank you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in the question doesn't work because the [`compare`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-) method violates the rules, e.g.

> The implementor must also ensure that the relation is transitive: `((compare(x, y)>0) && (compare(y, z)>0))` implies `compare(x, z)>0`.

For example:
`compare(A1, B2)` would return <0 because `A != B && 1 < 2`
`compare(B2, A3)` would return <0 because `B != A && 2 < 3`
`compare(A1, A3)` would return 0 because `A == A`, but the rules require it to return <0

When the rules are broken, the result is non-deterministic.

---

To build a collection of `ParseMessage` with only the most recent message from each contact, you should create a `Map`.

```
List<ParseMessage> cntct = /*...*/;

// Build map of contact to most recent message
Map<String, ParseMessage> cntctMap = cntct.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
        ParseMessage::getContact,
        Function.identity(),
        (a, b) -> a.getDateSent() >= b.getDateSent() ? a : b
));
```

If a collection of messages is needed, call values():

```
Collection<ParseMessage> cntctList = cntctMap.values();
```

Comment: You could also use `BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(ParseMessage::getDateSent))` as the merge function. I'm not saying that you should change it or that this is better, just that there's the possibility to write it like this.

Comment: Thanks for the Help Not sure why exactly the set implementation didn't work but this works and I loose no speed

Comment: Thanks for the great Explanation on why the tree set does not work for this case.